# Inequality with parameter

Tags: inequality

can someone show me how

$$2\sqrt{x^2 + 9a^2}\ \ge\ 2x\ +\ 9a \hspace{1cm}with \ a\ < 0$$

results in $$\forall x\ \in \ \mathscr{R}$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \le -\dfrac{9a}{2}$,we're done. Otherwise, square both sides: $4(x^2+9a^2) \ge 4x^2 + 36ax + 81a^2\iff 0 \ge 36ax+ 45a^2\iff 0 \ge9a(4x+5a)$. This is true since $a < 0$, and $x > \dfrac{-9a}{2}\implies 4x+5a > -18a+5a = -13a > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2\sqrt{x^2+9a^2}\geq2\sqrt{x^2}=2|x|\geq2x>2x+9a.$$